# Shall I use past perfect here?

Tags: past-tense

> I did not know they were still alive and kicking! I thought they split  up for years

I was wondering if "had split" would be better. I don't think so because for years states that it happened a long time ago and there is no real reason to put the action of splitting before not knowing they were still alive .

Comment: What does "they" refer to?  Please provide context Where is this text taken from?  - If you wrote it yourself please say so. If you are quoting, please provide source.

Comment: I suspect "alive" is being used figuratively.

Comment: they refer to a  group of music called XX  and yes alive is  being used figuratively and I wrote these 2 sentences

Comment: Correction - _for years_ states that the action _lasted a long time_.  Say **I thought they had split up years ago.**

Comment: So I am obliged to use past perfect

Comment: @YvesLefol - Well, I would; maybe an American wouldn't!

Comment: As an American, I would use the simple past, not the past perfect.  :-) The splitting up is a completed action in the past, so the simple past tense seems more natural to me.  This is one of the strange little differences between American English and British English!

Comment: _There is no real reason to put the action of splitting before not knowing they were still alive_. The split, if it had happened, would have been before you started to believe in it!

Comment: Or almost  at the same time as soon as I heard the band had split up